# How to feed a local placeholder of some function from main function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I defined some tensor operations in a function defining the placeholders locally. That function returns the result tensor, which I want to run/print from my main function (or maybe any other function). But I am not able to feed the placeholder's value from there.

A sample code of what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def f():
    a=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='name_a')
    b=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='name_b')
    addition=tf.add(a,b)
    return addition

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        var = f()
        answer = sess.run(var, feed_dict={a:[1],b:[2]})
        print(answer)
```

But, this shows error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'name_a' with dtype float

Obviously, I am understanding that I have not provided any way of connecting with those local tensors. Hence, technically the error is valid.
But is there any way by which I can feed the local placeholders of some function/method from some other method.
Does Tensorflow or Python provide any facility for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a `placeholder` or a `tensor` directly you can call `get_tensor_by_name`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def f():
    a=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='name_a')
    b=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='name_b')
    addition=tf.add(a,b)
    return addition

if __name__ == '__main__':
    var = f()
    a = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('name_a:0')
    b = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('name_b:0')
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(var, feed_dict={a:[1],b:[2]}))
```

> [3.]